# Interrupted SSI clock sequence

Tags: clock, encoder, data

I measured the following clock and data sequence (time axis is in microseconds) between a Beckhoff KL5001 encoder module and a 19-bit SSI encoder. Apparently the clock is interrupted 3 times before stopping finally.

I was not able to find more detailed description of such clock interruptions than e.g. this one: "A running transmission can be interrupted at any time by just stopping the clock."

It is not clear for me whether the data transmission should continue or start over. Looking at the data, the signal does not seem to start over. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host could be a microcontroller with SPI interface that works with 8-bit bytes, and therefore the transmission may not be continuous. Some 8-bit AVR MCUs had an SPI interface which basically needed one bit time between bytes so it was impossible to transfer with continuous clock on that MCU.

The gap between clocks is not long enough to trigger a timeout so the transmission continues after the pause. The gap needs to be about 20 microseconds for the timeout and these gaps are far below it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thank you! So, in the diagram above we can observe 25 (3x8 +1) clock cycles, correct?

Comment: @ChristianK. Yes 25 bits transferred.